# Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=12 "Cannot allocate memory" when i use the method requestAVAsset forVideo of PHImageManager

Tags: swift, ipad

```
let options = PHVideoRequestOptions()
                options.deliveryMode = .automatic
                options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
                let temp = PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, options: options) { avasset, audiomix, info in
                    if let avassetURL = avasset as? AVURLAsset {
                        do {
                            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: avassetURL.url, to: fileURL)
                            Log(info)
                            completion(fileURL)
                        }catch {
                            // most likely, the file didn't exist.  Don't sweat it
                            Log("Copy Video Fail: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        }
                    }else {
                        Log("COULD NOT CREATE EXPORT SESSION")
                        completion(nil)
                        return
                    }
                }
                Log("RESULT EXPORT: \(temp)")
```

I have the error:

YourProject(6353,0x16d5bf000) malloc: can't allocate region
:*** mach_vm_map(size=1785462784, flags: 100) failed (error code=3)
YourProject(6353,0x16d5bf000) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “388f64e38caa54b734c512a43373b3d7a573fc723c66fa32d5cb157aeafb5ac5.mp4” couldn’t be opened." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FDE7D8E9-3CDC-4EE1-8FEA-9FC3211CE51E/Documents/YourProject/Medias/388f64e38caa54b734c512a43373b3d7a573fc723c66fa32d5cb157aeafb5ac5.mp4, NSUnderlyingError=0x28146f9f0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=12 "Cannot allocate memory"}}

When i export the large video in ipad.
also i added permission Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I am having similar issue